# Submit form to (own) server from localhost

Tags: php, javascript, html, air

So I have a PHP script that takes an argument/variable from a HTML form, processes it and echoes some stuff; just as usual.

I would like to get this application to work in AIR. As (at last as far as I know), you cant run PHP in AIR apps, you'd have to do it on another server.

So how can I submit the form (that runs on localhost/AIR) to the PHP script on my server?
Another question would be fetching the results again and displaying them on a local page.

Comment: I've never used Adobe AIR, but if you *could* create a fake domain name through your `/etc/hosts` or similar file which is linking to `http://localhost/` and use that in your application. Just a thought...

Comment: good idea but unfortunately, I dont have root filesystem access on that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a form, for example:

```
<form name="formname" action="script.php" method="post">
```

...

You can change the action to:

http://www.site.com/script.php or even the path to the script locally.

That way even if you are running the form locally, it will still post to the action, no matter where it is.

If your form is hosted on the internet, and you try and post it to a local action, it will not work.